# NoMethodError undefined method `add_index' in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in the model

```
class Thorserver < ActiveRecord::Base
  add_index :Thorserver, [:ip, :mode], :unique => true
end
```

I see this error trying to insert to the table through the views

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `add_index' for #<Class:0x9a680494>):
app/models/thorserver.rb:2
app/controllers/testbeds_controller.rb:147:in `addresource'
```

The ruby version is ruby 1.8.6, rails version is Rails 2.3.8

Comment: Please read this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 3):

`add_index` is not a method of `ActiveRecord::Base`. That should be placed in your database migration.

You can add that statement to a migration in rails and it should add the uniqueness that you are looking for.

Another way of doing it would be to use `validates_uniqueness_of` validation.

I believe something like this should work `validates_uniqueness_of :ip, :scope => [:mode]`

However, note that since that's not done at the database level it is not guaranteed to be unique 100%. I would suggest still adding the index that you have in the migration and update your db with it as well as the uniqueness validation.

Comment: Is there any way to enforce uniqueness to combination of columns in ActiveRecord::Base.